# How is the . operator related to | and >?

Tags: bash, ftp

I'm writing a script that transfers files that are periodically added to a remote server. To do this I'd like to pull ls output from the remote server, then check it against a list of files that have already been downloaded.

I had a difficult time figuring out how to redirect the output from ls to a local file. I cam across [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/27612/why-is-my-ftp-output-file-blank/41441#41441), and found that 
`ls . localfile` works.

I've never come across the `.` operator for output redirection. How is it related to `>` and `|`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not. From the ftp(1) man page:

> dir [remote-directory] [local-file]
>
> Print a listing of the directory contents in the directory,
>      remote-directory, and, optionally, placing the output in
>      local-file.  If interactive prompting is on, ftp will prompt
>      the user to verify that the last argument is indeed the tar‐
>      get local file for receiving dir output.  If no directory is
>      specified, the current working directory on the remote
>      machine is used.  If no local file is specified, or
>      local-file is -, output comes to the terminal.

So when using the `dir` command you can specify a local file to dump the listing to. The `.` is just referring to the remote directory that you are listing (in the case of `.` the current directory).